# How to switch synced folder without reloading Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows, vagrant-provision

Environment:  Windows Host running Vagrant and VirtualBox with Ubuntu as the guest OS
Background:  Doing [basic provisioning inside Vagrantfile](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/basic_usage.html)

When switching between various sites, I have found that I have to first run `vagrant halt`, `cd` in the Windows CLI to the base folder of the site I next want to work on (where the Vagrantfile is stored), and then `vagrant up` again in order for the [synced folder](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/) in the guest OS to be mapped correctly to the code folder on the Windows host.  This shutting down and restarting takes more time than I would like.  I tried simply running `vagrant provision` after `cd`'ing in the Windows CLI to the folder of the site I want to work on, but this did not re-map the synced folder.  I also tried `vagrant suspend`, `cd`'ed to another site folder, and then ran `vagrant resume --provision`, but this did not re-map the synced folder either.  Is there any way to re-map the synced folder without going through the `vagrant halt`, `cd another_site`, `vagrant up` sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 Vagrantfile = 1 VirtualBox VM**

so basically you're in folder1/ with its own Vagrantfile, you have started and managed this VM. You now want to "switch" to another VM (not just a folder) so you need to shutdown the current VM, go to the folder2 and start this VM.

What you want is to have a single VM and multiple project folder (site) linked within this VM. some projects like [homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead) let you easily managed this. Otherwise you can manage yourself: you need a single Vagrantfile (so it will be only 1 VM) and then all your projects within this project structure.

Comment: Thank you.  I was making it harder than I needed to and can't believe I didn't think of that.